# How many features can we input for a SVM to classify?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am new to SVM classifiers. I read on the internet that SVM are binary classifiers and also many SVMs, as described in research papers, only take 2 features as the input.

(e.g. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html)

My question is, does it have to be 2 input features? Can we use more than 2? If so, how do we write this code in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no restriction on the number of features.

The syntax is exactly the same. For your tutorial, rather than

```
X = iris.data[:, :2]
```

That takes only $2$ columns, just change it to a bigger number if those columsn area in your dataframe. It is a common practice that the last column is the $y$ values of which case just to remove that column, just use $-1$.

For some online tutorials, sometimes we use $2$ features for the convenience of visualization only.

However, note that we do not want to use too many features as we want to build a model can be generalized. A simple model that works is better than a complicated model.